# Can numpy einsum() perform a cross-product between segments of a trajectory

Tags: python, numpy

I perform the cross product of contiguous segments of a trajectory (xy coordinates) using the following script:

```
In [129]:
def func1(xy, s):
    size = xy.shape[0]-2*s
    out = np.zeros(size)
    for i in range(size):
        p1, p2 = xy[i], xy[i+s]     #segment 1
        p3, p4 = xy[i+s], xy[i+2*s] #segment 2
       out[i] = np.cross(p1-p2, p4-p3)
    return out

def func2(xy, s):
    size = xy.shape[0]-2*s
    p1 = xy[0:size]
    p2 = xy[s:size+s]
    p3 = p2
    p4 = xy[2*s:size+2*s]

    tmp1 = p1-p2
    tmp2 = p4-p3
    return tmp1[:, 0] * tmp2[:, 1] - tmp2[:, 0] * tmp1[:, 1]


In [136]:
xy = np.array([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[2,4],[5,2],[9,9],[1,1]])
func2(xy, 2)

Out[136]:
array([ 0, -3, 16,  1, 22])
```

func1 is particularly slow because of the inner loop so I rewrote the cross-product myself (func2) which is orders of magnitude faster.

Is it possible to use the numpy einsum function to make the same calculation?

Comment: In my testing your `func2` is faster than the alternatives, even the new `cross`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`einsum` computes sums of products only, but you could shoehorn the cross-product into a sum of products by reversing the columns of `tmp2` and changing the sign of the first column:

```
def func3(xy, s):
    size = xy.shape[0]-2*s
    tmp1 = xy[0:size] - xy[s:size+s]
    tmp2 = xy[2*s:size+2*s] - xy[s:size+s]
    tmp2 = tmp2[:, ::-1]
    tmp2[:, 0] *= -1
    return np.einsum('ij,ij->i', tmp1, tmp2)
```

---

But `func3` is slower than `func2`.

```
In [80]: xy = np.tile(xy, (1000, 1))

In [104]: %timeit func1(xy, 2)
10 loops, best of 3: 67.5 ms per loop

In [105]: %timeit func2(xy, 2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 73.2 µs per loop

In [106]: %timeit func3(xy, 2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 108 µs per loop
```

Sanity check:

```
In [86]: np.allclose(func1(xy, 2), func3(xy, 2))
Out[86]: True
```

I think the reason why `func2` is beating `einsum` here is because the cost of setting of the loop in `einsum` for just 2 iterations is too expensive compared to just manually writing out the sum, and the reversing and multiplying eat up some time as well.

Comment: Thanks unutbu. I know that reversing the columns of a matrix using the common view based method is pretty slow too.

Answer (score 1):

`np.cross` is a smart little beast, that can handle broadcasting without any issue. So you can rewrite your `func2` as:

```
def func2(xy, s):
    size = xy.shape[0]-2*s
    p1 = xy[0:size]
    p2 = xy[s:size+s]
    p3 = p2
    p4 = xy[2*s:size+2*s]
    return np.cross(p1-p2, p4-p3)
```

and it will produce the correct result:

```
>>> func2(xy, 2)
array([ 0, -3, 16,  1, 22])
```

In the latest numpy it will likely run a tad faster than your code, as it was rewritten to minimize intermediate array creation. You can look at the source code (pure Python) [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/core/numeric.py#L1550).

Comment: The `cross` version you reference has major changes in Feb and June 2014, v1.9.1.  Rolling the axis of interest to the end, and using `multiply(...,out=c)` where possible.